# Change detection for an ondrop event when object property has changed

Tags: angular

I am building a drag and drop interface and think that I need to implement change detection in order to get this working properly.

My component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { GetStoryFunnelService } from '../../services/get-story-funnel.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-funnel-grid',
  templateUrl: './funnel-grid.component.html',
})
export class FunnelGridComponent implements OnInit {

    results: any;

    columnNames = [
        {id: 0, name: 'Opened', items: []},
        {id: 1, name: 'Responded', items: []},
        {id: 2, name: 'Material requested', items: []},
        {id: 3, name: 'Material sent', items: []},
        {id: 4, name: 'Interview requested', items: []},
        {id: 5, name: 'Interview completed', items: []},
        {id: 6, name: 'Follow up sent', items: []},
        {id: 7, name: 'Follow up responded', items: []},
        {id: 8, name: 'Article secured', items: []},
        {id: 9, name: 'Article published', items: []},
        {id: 10, name: 'Not interested', items: []}
    ];

    constructor(
        private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
        private getFunnel: GetStoryFunnelService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getFunnel.getStoryFunnel().subscribe(data => {
            this.results = data;
            console.log(this.results);
        });
    }

    onItemDrop(event: any) {
        alert('dropped');
        const dropId = event.nativeEvent.srcElement.id;
        const dropItem = event.dragData;
        const index = this.results.findIndex(item => {
            return item.contactId === dropItem.contactId;
        });
        this.results[index].storyFunnelStatusId = dropId;
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        console.log(this.results[index]);
    }

}
```

on when the `onItemDrop()` function is called it first gets the `id` of the element it is being dropped into, it then gets the object properties of the item that was dropped, then I find that object in the root `results` object, and finally I update the property. The `storyFunnelStatusId` is then used in my view to determine which column the `result` items are supposed to be associated with.

The problem I am having is that when the property value is changed, the view does not update. After some research I have learned this is because I have to manually initiate a change detection. Unfortunately I have *never* done anything like this before so I am not sure the best way to implement this?

**EDIT: THE RESULTS OBJECT LOOKS LIKE THIS:**

```
[
    {
        "contactId": 0,
        "contactName": "John Doe",
        "mediaOutletName": "Gadget",
        "pitchingInitiativeId": 0,
        "statusHistory": [
            {
                "completedDate": "2018-02-07T03:45:19.811Z",
                "storyFunnelId": 0,
                "storyFunnelStatusId": 0
            }
        ],
        "storyFunnelId": 0,
        "storyFunnelStatusId": 0,
        "updatedDate": "2018-02-07T03:45:19.811Z",
        "userId": 0
    }
]
```

**EDIT: TEMPLATE VIEW**

```
<div class="board-container">
    <div class="board-column" *ngFor="let column of columnNames">
        <div class="board-heading">
            {{ column.name }}
            <span class="count">4</span>
        </div>
        <div id="{{ column.id }}"
            class="board-body h-100"
            (onDrop)="onItemDrop($event)"
            droppable>
            <div class="card bg-light-blue mb-2" *ngFor="let item of (results | groupBy: column.id)" [dragData]="item" draggable>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-title mb-0">
                        <h6>
                            <span class="text-primary"><strong>{{ item.contactName }}</strong></span>
                            <span class="text-secondary">- {{ item.mediaOutletName }}</span>
                        </h6>
                        <button class="btn btn-transparent p-0">
                            <small><i class="fa fa-caret-down p-0"></i></small>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-text text-dark">
                        Sent: {{ item.updatedDate | date }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT CUSTOM PIPE**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'groupBy'
})

export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: any, groupId: number ): any {
        if (items instanceof Array) {
            return items.filter(items => items.storyFunnelStatusId === groupId);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your component's `results` property holding values of 'array' type?

Comment: @amal I update my post to show a snippet of what the results object looks like

Comment: Okay, since no template sections are shown, could you tell me what's the 'specific update' that you are not seeing reflected onto the view here from the component?

Comment: @amal I also added the template section. So basically what is going on here is that I have columns that are generated from and array and looped. Then within these columns I loop through the `results` object and apply a filter to them that filters where the `column.id` and the `results > item.storyFunnelStatusId` match. Then in my drag and drop interface when the onDrop method is called, it updates the `storyFunnelStatusId` property of the item dropped to match the new `column.id`. This is happening, I verified in the console. Now the view is not updating with the property change.

Comment: I should see the item in the new column!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, try this,

```
onItemDrop(event: any) {
        alert('dropped');
        const dropId = event.nativeEvent.srcElement.id;
        const dropItem = event.dragData;
        const index = this.results.findIndex(item => {
            return item.contactId === dropItem.contactId;
        });
        this.results[index].storyFunnelStatusId = dropId;
        this.results = [ ...this.results ]; // creating a new array reference and assigning to itself using the spread operator
        this.columnNames = [ ...this.columnNames ];
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        console.log(this.results[index]);
}
```

Comment: getting closer...the behavior I am seeing now is that the items `storyFunnelStatusId` is changed as it should be, but now the item is being completely removed from the view.

Comment: didn't quite get you there, so you mean something's updated in view but then something else vanishes from it?

Comment: so i console logged just `this.results` and the object is getting updated with the new value. honestly it was doing this before. the change now is that the effected item is just being removed from the view. does that make sense?

Comment: Okay, gotcha. This is a bit of an overkill, but could you try this as well after the spread operator assignment shown above: `this.columnNames = [ ...this.columnNames ];`. Updated it in the answer too.

Comment: no, that didn't work. I am starting to wonder if I need to detect changes in my custom `groupBy`  pipe as well.

Comment: added it to my original post

Comment: i removed the pipe just to test, and no effect, same result